# each session element id - django

Tags: django, session

I have many products in session and i show them in this way in template:

```
{% for name, price, number in request.session.products %}
 <tr>
   <td valign="top">{{name}}</td>
   <td valign="top">{{price}}</td>
   <td valign="top">{{number}}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I have two questions here:

1. How can I make 4th iterator variable to get the whole session instance in one loop.
2. I use that 4th variable to get the session id of each session instance. But just for test I tried `{{request.session.session_key}}`, but it is not showing anything. how can I get the id of each session?

I also tried `{{request.session._session_key}}`, but it is saying: `Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores`